# Strings transcoding in Java

Tags: java, string, encoding, codepages

I've found a piece of code recently, which does the following:

```
String s = ... // whatever
...
s = new String(s.getBytes(myEncoding), myEncoding);
```

For me it appears to be absolutely non-sense.

Is it possible that under certain circumstances (some specific combination of locale settings, used technologies, etc.), this code will do something useful?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

yes, that code is generally nonsense.  yes, it's possible that that code *could* be doing "something" to the string (probably not anything good).  generally speaking, if you have already incorrectly converted bytes to chars, trying to re-convert is rarely going to give you legitimate results.  (there may be isolated instances where the right combination of character encodings may work).

Comment: This could simply be bad semantics but important code. myEncoding could reference a custom CharsetEncoder. A CharsetEncoder can replace unknown characters with a custom byte array and then strip it on re-encoding. You could probably implement something like html escaping using a custom CharsetEncoder. If that's the case, this code seems too-clever-for-its-own-good. I'd recommend replacing the encode-decode line with a better-named method.

Comment: 2 ccoakley
myEncoding is plain ISO8859-1 encoding